# add id or class to flash message

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is there a way to add a class or an id to a specific flash message? I need to have some messages fade away and some persist. I would like to do this based on a html class.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is nothing magical about what can put in the flash. It's just a hash that is stuffed in the session and cleared out for you.

You could (for example) do

```
flash[:notice] = {:class => :urgent, :body => 'hello'}
```

And then in your layout

```
- if flash[:notice]
  %div{:class => flash[:notice][:class]}
    = flash[:notice][:body]
```

But there's definitely more than one way to do this - you could just use one class when it's `flash[:notice]`, another for `flash[:error]` etc

Answer (score 3):

Flash messages are simply stored in a hash, `flash`.  In your view, you might iterate over all of your flash messages like this:

```
<% flash.each do |key, msg| %>
  <%= content_tag :div, msg, :id => key %>
<% end %>
```

You could always check for a specific message and append a specific class.  Maybe something like:

```
<% flash.each do |key, msg| %>
  <% if msg.include? 'fatal' %>
    <%= content_tag :div, msg, :id => key, :class => 'fatal' %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Here's a railscast with more information on flash messages.

http://railscasts.com/episodes/18-looping-through-flash

Answer (score 0):

Add a class:

```
<%= content_tag(:p, notice, class: 'notice') if notice %>
<%= content_tag(:p, alert,  class: 'alert' ) if alert  %>
```

Add an id:

```
<%= content_tag(:p, notice, id: 'notice') if notice %>
<%= content_tag(:p, alert,  id: 'alert' ) if alert  %>
```

It renders (example):

```
<p class="alert">Invalid email or password.</p>
<p id="alert">Invalid email or password.</p>
```